# Add last date column of the month based on local date in PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want to add the column of the last working day of the month from my data (in this case, create the column `last date`). My data includes dates, but only working days are included - no Sundays or holidays. How can I obtain the month - end closing date based on this data.

For example, my last day of April is `28-Apr-2023`, not `30-April-2023`; `EOMONTH(Data[Date], 0)` can't be used. Similarly for May, ...

[image]

Comment: Do you have a master holiday schedule to use, or do you just mean last weekday? Or do you need a custom measure that is responsive to country selection?

Comment: If you want this to be in accord with the users locale, you will need to have a table (or an api) that provides the holiday dates and weekend days for the locale.

Comment: I already have a master holiday schedule. But there is another way is that in my data there is data by date already, just need to max the date of the month. In **measure**, if I use the ```lastdate``` function and filter by month, I can find out the result. But in this situation I want to add a column. Either way is fine, as long as I get the answer.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] Please: Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give an exact answer without seeing your data structure, but the basic idea is to perform a LASTDATE() calculation filtered to exclude non-business days. This assumes you have a `'Calendar'[EOMONTH]'` column (`EOMONTH('Calendar'[Date],0)`).

```
CALCULATE(
    LASTDATE( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[EOMONTH] ),
    WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date],3) < 5
)
```

This assumes a standard weekend of Saturday/Sunday. To change that by locale, you would need a weekend fact table related to the Calendar dimension and a locale dimension. You would need the same structure to have a locale-specific holiday schema.